# NSDateFormat issue in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

I am getting Date from server side through soap web service and I used below code to formate the date

```
 NSString *dateString = @"2017-01-16T11:34:23.2424222+05:30";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *formatedDate = [self applyTimezoneFixForDate:dateString];
    dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:formatedDate];

    NSLog(@"Parsed date is %@", date);
```

but its returning nil value.
Any one know the correct date format to compile this date ?

**Update**

I am getting two different date type format from my web service.
Actually server side sending **1/16/2017 11:34:23 AM**  date and from app side after xml parsing I am getting **2017-01-16T11:34:23.2424222+05:30**, In same service for **7/4/2015 5:21:47 AM** date from app side Iam  getting **2015-07-04T05:21:47.083** ,

My concern is , Is it possible to generalize the Date format and convert all date string format to NSDate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added the `millisecond` formate with your `dateFormate`, so change it to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ`. Whole could would be like.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2017-01-16T11:34:23.2424222+05:30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *formatedDate = [self applyTimezoneFixForDate:dateString];
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ";
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:formatedDate];

NSLog(@"Parsed date is %@", date);
```

Comment: @SivaprasadKm Welcome mate :)

Comment: Actually server side sending 1/16/2017 11:34:23 AM and from app side I am getting 2017-01-16T11:34:23.2424222+05:30 so I converted using above formatter, In same service I am getting another date 7/4/2015 5:21:47 AM and from app side getting 2015-07-04T05:21:47.083 but code failed to format this date ,do you have any idea ? Is it possible to write formatter for both this two format generally ?

Comment: I got the result using the format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS for 2015-07-04T05:21:47.083, But still problem is exist, Is it possible to format both ?

Comment: @SivaprasadKm Don't get it what you are try to say, please edit your question with your new problem.